# In PHP, how do I read an unreliable web page?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use Curl in PHP to read a unreliable web page. The page is often unavailable because of server errors. However, I still need to read it if it's available. Additionally, I don't want the unreliability of the web page to effect my code. I would like my PHP to fail gracefully and move on. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
    function get_url_contents($url){
        $crl = curl_init();
        $timeout = 2;
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $ret = curl_exec($crl);
        curl_close($crl);
        return $ret;
    }
    $handle = get_url_contents ( 'http://www.mydomain.com/mypage.html' );
?>
```

Comment: And that code isn't working? Do you get an error?

Comment: you know how to fetch it and you know how to set a timeout, so what is your question?

Comment: It's not failing gracefully. Unable to find an error.

Comment: just check if your `$ret` is containing a string you can search for with `strstr`. if not return false. outside your function you just have to ceck your `$handle!==false` and you are good to go.

Comment: So this would fix it?

`if ( $handle !== false ) {
    $handle = get_url_contents ( 'http://www.mydomain.com/mypage.html' );
}`

Comment: Or should I check on $ret inside the function and "break" if there is no string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test the HTTP code to see if the page was successfully retrieved by testing the HTTP Response code. I can't remember if >200 and <302 are the correct code ranges though, have a quick peak at [http response codes](http://www.helpwithpcs.com/courses/html/html_http_status_codes.htm) If you use this method.

```
<?php
    function get_url_contents($url){
        $crl = curl_init();
        $timeout = 2;
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $ret['pagesource'] = curl_exec($crl);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($crl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($crl);

        if($httpcode >=200 && $httpcode<302) {
         $ret['response']=true;
        } else {
         $ret['response']=false;
        }

        return $ret;
    }
    $handle = get_url_contents ( 'http://192.168.1.118/newTest/mainBoss.php' );
    if($handle['response']==false){
          echo 'page is no good';
    } else {
             echo 'page is ok and here it is:' . $handle['pagesource'] . 'DONE.<br>';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead, CURL is not super recommanded anymore as i've heard since PHP wrappers offer much better performance and are always available anywhere you go:

```
$currentcontext = stream_context_get_default();
stream_context_set_default(stream_context_create(array('timeout' => 2)));
$content = file_get_contents('url', $context);
stream_context_set_default($currentcontext);
```

This will set the default stream context to timeout after 2 seconds and get the content of the url via a stream wrapper that should be there in all php versions from 5.2 and up for sure;

You are not obligated to restore the default context depending on your site's code but it's always a good thing to do. If you don't, then this operation can be achieved in only 2 lines of code...

Comment: Interesting, I read elsewhere that file_get_contents wasn't recommended as a lot of shared hosts disable it.

Comment: Its not file_get_contents, its the fopen_wrappers that are disabled but should not. There is an option to prevent distant includes but hosters usually do it wrong and disable the whole thing instead of preventing only distant includes. Don't know for sure tho... But this methods is the one recommended by Zend in the exam for PHP Engineer Certification.

Comment: Pretty sure I've run into problems myself before with `file_get_contents` at MediaTemple. Thanks, I will try it if I can't get Curl option to work above.