# Thirdparty payment Processor API call is failing within WHMCS payment gateway callback file

Tags: xml

I had successfully set up and integrated a third party payment integration system on WHMCS. Inorder to Validate callback authenticity, the gateway provides a method of verifying that a callback originated from them as shown in code below:

```
$mertid ='secretmerchantID';
$amt = '10000';
$tranxid = 'gtPay130958397220820';
$hashkey ='secretclientkey';

$hash =  hash('sha512', $mertid . $tranxid . $hashkey);

$url = 'https://ibank.gtbank.com/GTPayService/gettransactionstatus.xml?mertid='.$mertid.'&amount='.$amt.'&tranxid='.$tranxid.'&hash='.$hash;


$xmlString = file_get_contents($url);
if($xmlString === false)
{
    echo "Response Description: GTPAY Verification service failed to  open. 
}
else
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString );

    var_dump($xml);
}
```

I am using the file_get_contents function to read the API response into a string, then simplexml_load_string function to Interprets the string of XML into an object with properties containing the data held within the xml string. On each successful transaction run $xml=simplexml_load_string($jString), returns FALSE.

However when I call this code in a file directly in a browser on WAMP using the same transaction values, then $xml=simplexml_load_string($jString), returns the string of XML into an object as expected. Also when I place the file on a different remote host and call it in browser, it also returns the string of XML into an object.

Strangely, when I place this code in a file within the WHMCS root folder and I attempt to call directly in a browser using the same successful transaction values used above, then $xml=simplexml_load_string($jString), returns FALSE again.

What may be restricting this call to the Third party API call within the WHMCS install?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the WHMCS inbuilt curlCall helper function below which is recommended for any remote API connections and I am making successful calls to the remote APIs now:

```
$url = 'http://www.whmcs.com/';
$postfields = array(
    'a' => 'b',
    'c' => 'd',
);
$options = array(
    'CURLOPT_TIMEOUT' => '300',
);
$response = curlCall($url, $postfields, $options);
```

You may read all about it here:http://docs.whmcs.com/Internal_Functions#CURL_Connections.

While I did not verify this, It has been documented here( [In PHP, how do I read an unreliable web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156573/in-php-how-do-i-read-an-unreliable-web-page)), that disabling fopen_wrappers inhibites remote API calls using file_get_contents. May be this was disabled on my web host; thus causing me problems in the first instance. I hope this points someone else in the right direction.

Comment: May I ask you a question?